# Neo4j match path exclude node with certain label

Tags: neo4j

I am having a issue to retrieve path in neo4j exclude certain label.

Foe example, I have

```
               -->(h)-->(j)
              /
(a)-->(b)-->(c)-->(d)-->(i)
        \           
         -->(f)-->(g)
```

with `h` node has a `Deleted` label.

I have query

```
MATCH path = (n)-[*]->(child) where id(n)={id of node a} and NOT child:Deleted RETURN path
```

then I want this query to return the full path but exclude the subtree of node `h` since node `h` is `Deleted`.

the return tree should be like

```
(a)-->(b)-->(c)-->(d)-->(i)
        \           
         -->(f)-->(g)
```

But the query seems not working.

Can any one help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

What worked for me is a list comprehension over nodes in the path:

```
MATCH path = ()-[*]->()
WHERE NONE(n IN nodes(path) WHERE n:Deleted)
RETURN path
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_with_config) with this, using the path expander functionality along with a blacklist to prevent expanding to nodes with labels in the blacklist during traversal.

```
match (a)
where id(a) = {id of node a}
call apoc.path.expandConfig(a, {labelFilter:'-Deleted'}) yield path
return path
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to check both nodes for the label:

```
match p=((a)-[r:NEXT]->(b))
where  not (a:Deleted or b:Deleted)
return p
```

here's another example:

```
match (a)-[r:NEXT]->(b) 
where  not (("Deleted" in labels(a)) or
            ("Deleted" in labels(b))) 
return a, r, b
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I actually want to check all nodes, not just a and b.

Comment: This is a pattern to match, so it will check all nodes. I duplicated your graph here and this does what you want.

Comment: not sure I understand correctly. Looks like this only retrieve up to b node and not going further to c or f node or even further.

Comment: I think you're mixing placeholders with labels. The a and b in my match are generic to the graph and do not correspond to any labels.

Comment: Try that pattern with your data and see what happens.

Comment: Yep, I did tried with it. First of all, there is no relationship with label named "NEXT". if I remove the ":NEXT", it will only return a-r->b. In my question, I also need to query by id(a)=1234

Comment: Create a graph like you've posted using "NEXT" relationships, and you'll see that what I posted works. Then you can take that concept and apply it to your current graph to arrive at your solution.