# How to store hierarchical data in redis graph and retrieve a sub tree out of it?

Tags: redis, cypher, redisgraph

id | name | parent_id

ab | file  | de

ad | song |  de

bc | Bob |ad

mn | open.txt | bc

Answer (score 2):

Assuming 
`ab` is the ID of `file` and `bc` is the parent ID of `file`
then to store you can either use the [bulk-insert utility](https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/redisgraph-bulk-loader)

Or you can use the following Cypher query:

```
CREATE (A {id:'ab', name: 'file'}), (B {id:'bc', name: 'folder'}), (A)-[:child]->(B)
```

To query, depending on the data you would like to extract use a Cypher query similar to:

```
MATCH (c)-[:child]->(p) RETURN c,p
```

Comment: `GRAPH.QUERY Makinga "MATCH (b:Resource)-[:child_of*1..]->(r:Resource{Id:'6e3f67da-43ed-11e9-b149-d3f886f8337c'})  RETURN count(b) as count`

Comment: I was using Variable length relationships but it was taking lot of time to process the results for larger graph i.e 1,75,000 nodes

Answer (score 1):

For the type of query you're running, I believe it would be better if you maintained a reverse edge [:parent] and modify your query as such:

```
GRAPH.QUERY Makinga "MATCH (r:Resource{Id:'6e3f67da-43ed-11e9-b149-d3f886f8337c'})-[:parent*1..]->(b:Resource) RETURN count(b) as count"
```

This is related to the way RedisGraph describes connections and applies filters.

Comment: As of now does redis graph provides a way to skip a path in a sub tree i.e if we are fetching a subtree from parents to children and i want that one path sub tree out of the whole subtree must be excluded from the result . I have folder file hierarchy system so when i mark a particular folder as trash and  then get sub-resources it should skips that folders and all the child within the folder nodes as well.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36439749/neo4j-match-path-exclude-node-with-certain-label ] I want the exact same thing mentioned in this post but in redisgraph none and in are not available as of now .So is  there any hack to it ?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't think of a way around this, we'll need to improve our support of the Path object, my only suggestion would be disconnecting folders/files marked as trash, from the rest of the graph.